# Sort by Frequency

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I want to sort the elements in an array by their frequency.

```
Input: 2 5 2 8 5 6 8 8 

Output: 8 8 8 2 2 5 5 6
```

Now one solution to this would be:

- Sort the elements using Quick sort or Merge sort. O(nlogn)
- Construct a 2D array of element and count by scanning the sorted array. O(n)
- Sort the constructed 2D array according to count. O(nlogn)

Among the other probable methods that I have read, one uses a Binary Search Tree and the other uses Hashing.

Could anyone suggest me a better algorithm? I know the complexity can't be reduced. But I want to avoid so many traversals.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting an array by increasing frequency of element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391695/sorting-an-array-by-increasing-frequency-of-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform one pass on the array without sorting it, and on a separate structure go counting how many times you find an element. This could be done on a separate array, if you know the ranges of the elements you'll find, or on a hash table, if you don't. In any case this process will be O(n). Then you can perform a sort of the second structure generated (where you have the count), using as sort parameter the amount that each element has associated. This second process is, as you said O(nlogn) if you choose a proper algorithm.

For this second phase I would recommend using Heap sort, by the means of a priority queue. You can tell the queue to order the elements by the count attribute (the one calculated on step one), and then just add the elements one by one. When you finish adding, the queue will be already sorted, and the algorithm has the desired complexity. TO retrieve your elements in order you just have to start popping.