# Sorting an Array - Sorting the Frequency in descending order

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

In C# I'm having difficulties sorting my array; specifically I'm trying to make the Frequency sort in descending order while having each frequency maintain its proper key or point value on the left.

For instance, the output should resemble what it does now, but the values will be staggered instead of 26-2.

Ex:

```
26------50
23------754
20------334
25------96
```

and so on...

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[] freq = new int[27];

        int total;

        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {

            total = r.Next(1, 14);

            total += r.Next(1, 14);

            freq[total]++;

        }

        freq = freq.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine("*Total*\t\t*Freq*");
        Console.WriteLine();
        int key = 26;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 24; i++) //Total point range being identified
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" {0}\t{1,12}", key, freq[i]);
            key--;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: The frequencies are not correlated with the proper point values on the left. The numbers shouldn't be perfectly descending on the left from 26-2.

Comment: Can you tell what you expect, by editing your question? I think you should simply change the condition in for loop `for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)`

Comment: Updated, but yeah, staggered values on the left, so long as those left values are the correct with the appropriate frequencies on the right

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting an array by increasing frequency of element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391695/sorting-an-array-by-increasing-frequency-of-element)

Comment: Note that this link is in C++. The general concepts are the same, however.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. Can you please show an example of your input data and then the desired output for that specific input?